# Check for existance of facebook permalinked message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to check if a certain post, given by its permalink, still exists in a group on facebook.

I tried with lynx and wget, expecting a 404 if the post had been deleted, but I got  the message "your browser is not supported". Amazingly, facebook uses around 500k of javascript with trackers, arrays of language translations etc...

I've been looking at graphAPI, but it appears I have to make an app, which then have to be approved by facebook, then installed by an admin in the group.

Neither of these things are likely to happen.

Are there any "3rd-party" API's to facebook which allows (read-only) access to a facebook group as an user?

My last option is starting a VNC-session, start a browser, log into facebook, then periodically feed the browser an url from a table, wait a few seconds, capture a section of the screen, and if there is no text on it, (i.e. all white), then the message is gone.

This is possible; I've done it before to check if a list of websites produced the desired result and generate a page of miniatures.

Comment: What for do you need this in the first place?

Comment: In a particular group, members are not supposed to delete message, and also, some admin keep deleting my messages. I just want to know when it happens.

Comment: Sounds rather shady to me. But anyway, according to docs it is a requirement for an app to be “installed” in the group, apparently regardless of group type. Other than that, scraping would be your only option … but that is not allowed without explicit prior permission from Facebook. You already came across the 404 they respond with when you try and request a page in a “fake” browser … and they have other measures in place to detect such attempts as well. Best case scenario, you will only get the IP address of the machine you want to run this from blocked, worst case maybe even your account.

Comment: the main question here is: why would an admin delete your messages? does it happen that often? what group is that?

Comment: @04FS No, I didn't get a 404, regardless if the post existed or not, I get a 500k javascript just rendering "Browser not supported, use one of these -> "

Comment: Yeah that’s what I meant, wasn’t sure if they issue that with a 404 status code or not, but that document saying “browser not supported” means you ran into their first line of defense against such “fake” requests already. Wget has probably identified as itself via the User-Agent header, and Facebook rejects request that do not look like they were made by a “normal” browser in that regard.